# Which are the effects of the multiplication on the matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am not understanding what the following question is asking:

> b) Which are the effects of the multiplication on the matrix A?

Where:

$$A = \left (\begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & 5\end{matrix} \right)$$

$$I_{12} = \left (\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right)$$

The first question was asking:

> a) Compute or state "not defined" $I_{12}$A.

And I answered that the multiplication is defined and the resulted matrix is:

$$I_{12} = \left (\begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right)$$

What I am not understanding is what they are asking in point `b)`, could you please clarify me?

Comment: I think you should double check your product.

Comment: By "how does $I_{12}$ affect $A$", I think they mean "how does multiplying by $I_{12}$ affect $A$"? I.e., what results from the product, and can you describe it in words? See @reveillark's answer.

Comment: It seems strangely worded but that's what I believe that's what it's really asking. For further interpretation, you should contact your instructor if this is for a course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I_{ij}$ be a matrix with zeros, except for row $i$, column $j$ where the entry is $1$. E.g. $$ I_{12} = \left (\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right)$$

Then $I_{ij}A$ will be a matrix where the $i$th row will be the $j$th row of $A$, and the rest of the rows will be zeros. For our example we get

$$I_{12}A = \left (\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right). $$

As you can see the resultant matrix has the $1$st row be the $2$nd row of $A$, and the rest zero.

Similarly, the matrix $A I_{ij}$ will have the $j$th column be the $i$th column of $A$, and the rest of the columns will be zero. For your example you will get

$$AI_{12} = \left (\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0\end{matrix} \right). $$
As you can see the resultant matrix has the $2$nd column be the $1$st column of $A$, and the rest are zero.

Comment: It should be correct, you can test it for different $I_{ij}$ to verify.

Comment: What I have written works in general when $A$ and $I_{ij}$ are square matrices of same sizes. You might be interested in [permutation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), which takes the concepts further.

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo or something with your resulting matrix. The real answer is:

$$I_{12}A=\left (\begin{matrix} 1 &2&3\\ 0 & 0 &0\\ 0& 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right )$$

Question (b) is probably refering to the fact that multiplying $A$ by $I_{12}$ gives you a matrix whose first row is the second row of $A$, and whose other rows are all null.

Comment: Check http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D%20times%20%7B%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B2%2C-1%2C5%7D%7D

What you've computed is $AI_{12}$, but you were asked to compute $I_{12}A$.